# How are things stored in memory

Tags: c, computer-science

I just started learning C and I learned that every byte of memory has an address.

My question is, what is the address of an integer that takes 2 bytes of memory?

What if we have some data that takes 9 bits of memory? I think of memory as a long block of boxes of size 1 byte with an address. 9 bits occupies one box and 1/9 of the next one, what happens to the remaining 8/9 of the box?

Comment: FYI there are 8 bits in a byte.

Comment: if you speak about literal integers there are no address, they are part of the code in the instructions themselves

Comment: @ChristopherMoore that's not strictly true, it's just the most common byte size

Comment: @UnholySheep Oops sorry didn't know that thanks!

Comment: if you have a bit field of 9 bits and you have a memory of bytes having 8 bits your bit field will use 2 bytes. May be the other 7 bits will be used, all depends on the context, and options used by the compiler to reduce size etc. Anyway the address of a data is the address of its first byte whose can be the higher or lower byte depending on big/little indian

Comment: @Bruno, it can be the MSB or LSB, but not the higher or lower byte. The address is the first byte of the data item

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this is what I wanted to say

Comment: @ChristopherMoore this is why `CHAR_BIT` is defined through _limit.h_

Comment: The short answer to your question is, the address of any particular piece of data is the base address of where the data begins in memory.  The number of "boxes" that get allocated depends on both the platform and size of the data being created.  In your example, of 9 bits.  The system would allocate the memory needed to hold 2 bytes at a minimum.

For instance, I worked on a Analog Devices DSP that allocated a minimu of 32-bit  chunk of memory.  A `char ch;` would get allocated 32 bits.  An `int i;` would also get 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The 2018 C standard says in 6.2.6.1 2:

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
>   order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified [in the C standard] or implementation-defined.

The standard allows implementations flexibility with bit-fields. Generally, consecutive bit-fields may share parts of bytes, or the implementation may separate them and leave some bits unused.

Taking the address of an object in C yields a pointer. Pointers in C point to whole objects; no distinction is made for which byte they point to, except for objects that are themselves single bytes, of course. When a pointer is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result is a pointer to the lowest-addressed byte in the object (per 6.3.2.3 7). However, this does not mean the original pointer was represented with that address.

Comment: Good and correct answer, perhaps too much deep for this question.